# Difference in C# release, standalone exe or click once installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and I'm writing in C# (console program). I used to output a standalone .exe file from the debug folder (just copying the single .exe file to the client computers).

Now, it happens that different clients needs a different connection string. My solution was to copy the .exe file and also the .exe.config file from the debug folder. Modifying the config file will then directs the program to use different connection strings.

The concern is:

1. How about the other files in the debug folder, should I be copying them to the client computer as well? (e.g. .exe.manifest or .vhost files? )
2. Or shall I release the program into click-once file and install them into the client? But it would be quite troublesome and time consuming to install and uninstall the program on  many computers (during version upgrade), also more complicated to call the program from bat files?

I used to just use the .exe file from the debug folder. But when I found out that the .exe actually reads from the .exe.config, I wonder sole use in the .exe would result in leaks in the program?

Comment: Why do you DEPLOY a DEBUG version at all? Why not a release version?

Comment: Well.... just because of convenience..........